# Vmware Workstation 11 installation MSI failed in Windows 8.1

Tags: installation, vmware-workstation

I get a MSI failed message every time when I install Vmware Worksatation 11 on my windows 8.1 computer. I've tried to clear previous temp data but it doesn't work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and have fixed it.

Try to disable Hyper-V on Control Panel >>> Programs >>> Turn windows features on or of >>> Unselect Hyper-V >>> Click Ok and restart your computer

Comment: I didn't see Hyper-V. Can you be more specific? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you attempt a VMware Workstation 11 install, and it fails part-way through, a reboot typically addresses the install failure. If not, can you:

post some more information about what the error is

post the %TEMP%\vmsetup*.log files from your failed install attempt

Comment: The MSI    'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\vmware_1427252558\vmware workstation.msi' failed.

Comment: Yes, well, that's not very helpful at all. Are you able to post log files?